# Этимология слова "геенна"

Tags: этимология

Ад еще называют "геенна огненная". А что за слово "геенна"? Русское ли оно и какое у него происхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это слово с иврита. Ге Хином (долина Енона),  место где жители древнего Иерусалима сжигали мусор и мёртвых животных  (возможно имела ритуальное значение в языческих жертвоприношениях). Используется для обозначения ада.

Comment: @Людмила, я написал, что возможно данная долина имела ритуальное значение в языческие времена, но так как прямых свидетельств этого до нас не дошло, то распространятся на эту тему дальше не счёл нужным. Но, спасибо, за уточнение

Answer (score 0):

По Викисловарю - не только животных, там совершались языческие обряды с поклонением Молоху и принесением человеческих жертв. Позднее это место было проклято и превращено в свалку мусора и непогребённых трупов, где постоянно горели огни, уничтожавшие гниение. Потому и ад - для обитателей проклятого места.

Comment: Не знаю, кто переделал в ответ, у меня был комментарий - с Вашим ответом полностью согласна.